# Yodlee cobrand login does not allow successful login

Tags: curl, command-line-interface, yodlee

I'm trying to learn the yodlee developer portal.  I have signed up and now going the the Getting Started at the cobrand login.  I have tried to do the request like they have in the documentation.  What is the correct way to get the cobrand context with the correct params?

```
➜  perceptor git:(develop) http -f POST https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl/restserver/v1/cobrand/login cobrandLogin=sbCobxxxxxxxxxx cobrancdPassword=xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx 

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2017 19:44:44 GMT
Server: Unknown
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
yodlee-ref-id: m1497123885400E4t27g000000NLVYi-1

{
    "errorCode": "Y001", 
    "errorMessage": "loginName and password required", 
    "referenceCode": "u1497123885399Y4O27X"
}
```

Afterwards I thought maybe the params were named wrong and tried changing them but that really does come back as a Bad Request.

```
➜  perceptor git:(develop) http -f POST 
cobrandLogin=sbCobxxxxxxxxxx cobrancdPassword=xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx        

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2017 19:45:17 GMT
Server: Unknown
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
yodlee-ref-id: H1497123917473U4x26Z000000NLJYR-1

{
    "errorCode": "Y800", 
    "errorMessage": "Invalid value for cobrandParam", 
    "referenceCode": "p1497123917471e4n26B"
}
```

## Updated info

I was able to get cobrand login to work following @Krithik advice on the json structure.

```
{ "cobrand": 
    { 
        "cobrandLogin": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        "cobrandPassword": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx", 
        "locale": "en_US"
    }
}
```

I am still having trouble finishing the user login portion.  I am trying to run this.  With the `$COBRAND=Authorization: {cobrandSession=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}` and a json structure.

```
{
    "cobrandName": "Name of the cobrand",
    "loginName": "sbMemxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

➜  perception-ai git:(develop) ✗ http POST https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl/restserver/v1/user/login $COBRAND < user_login.json -vvv  
POST /ysl/restserver/v1/user/login HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: {cobSession=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 126
Content-Type: application/json
Host: developer.api.yodlee.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.6

{
    "cobrandName": "Name of the cobrand", 
    "loginName": "sbMemxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 21:09:18 GMT
Server: Unknown
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
yodlee-ref-id: y1497301758768V4x26C000000NLsYs-1

{
    "errorCode": "Y001", 
    "errorMessage": "loginName and password required", 
    "referenceCode": "w1497301758768O4L26p"
}
```

## Update Again

Changing the user login structure as below will be a successful login.

```
{
    "user":
    {
        "cobrandName": "Name of the cobrand",
        "loginName": "sbMemxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do a cobrand login using-

{
    "cobrand":      {
      "cobrandLogin": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "cobrandPassword": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "locale": "en_US"
     }
}

CURL command:

curl -X POST \
  URL/v1/cobrand/login \

-d '{
    "cobrand":      {
      "cobrandLogin": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "cobrandPassword": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "locale": "en_US"
     }
}'

Hope this helps.

Comment: this has helped alot yodlee documentation is not really complete it seems saying one thing one place and another thing else where.  Can you verify that the user login is using the correct structure in my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

The user login must look like this-

> {
>       "user":      {
>         "loginName": "sbMemxxxxxxxx3",
>         "password": "sbMemxxxxxxxxxxxx3",
>         "locale": "en_US"
>        } }

And ensure to pass Authorization in the request header and it must look like this-

> *Authorization:cobSession="Cobrand Session token value to be pasted here"*

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik